# Binding TextBox values to a generated list in a control layer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a program that reads TextBox values from a list, implements them and then when they are changed (on focus lost) the list values update for the user's eyes.

TLDR: change text box values, a value in a list changes

I want to be able to use data binding in my refactoring stage, as dozen of lines of code are impractical when I am working with a lot of data.

Unfortunately, I don't really know data binding. Can anyone give me guidance on what to do in this scenario?

`Data.cs`

```
    protected bool _Enabled;
    protected long _SensorId;
    protected float _Min;
    protected float _Maxe;
    protected SensorType _SType;
```

.

And where it links to:

`Controller.cs`

```
    List<Sensor> _Sensors = new List<Sensor>();
```

This links to Sensor ID, if it helps explain anything

.

What is displayed:

`MainPage.xaml`

```
<TextBox Name="txtMin_1" Text="" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
<TextBox Name="txtMin_2" Text="" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
<TextBox Name="txtMin_3" Text="" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
<TextBox Name="txtMin_4" Text="" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
```

I would like it so in `Text` I can use `Text="{Binding}"` to pull from the list, all the values that the text boxes use

Does what I'm asking make sense, and can anyone help? If it doesn't make sense please ask, as I'm happy to provide all the information I can give.

EDIT: Progress update

So here is the code I've added from the answer provided:

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
        Controller = new Controller(this);
        this.DataContext = Controller.Sensors;
```

`Controller.cs`

```
    private List<Sensor> _sensors;
    public List<Sensor> Sensors
    {
        get { return _sensors; }
        set { _sensors = value; }
    }
```

I also added a dummy that would change the values, to check that they were being retrieved, this did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Property for your List and then bind the specific elements to the textboxes like:

```
<TextBox Name="txtMin_1" Text="{Binding Sensors[0]}" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
<TextBox Name="txtMin_2" Text="{Binding Sensors[1]}" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
<TextBox Name="txtMin_3" Text="{Binding Sensors[2]}" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
<TextBox Name="txtMin_4" Text="{Binding Sensors[3]}" LostFocus="MinMaxValueChange"/>
```

and in your controller.cs:

```
private List<Sensor> _sensors;

public List<Sensor> Sensors
{
    get { return _sensors; }
    set { _sensors = value; }
}
```

Important is, that you set the DataContext of your MainPage.xaml to the Controller (i assume that is your viewmodel).

Here are some links that might be usefull to databinding and mvvm:

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahakgupta/simple-data-binding-in-wpf/
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level

Comment: Thank you for this. By ViewModel, do you mean what is seen by the user, or what, this is strange to me? Regardless, I have implimented what you have said, but my `public List<Sensor> Sensors` has no references, I'm sure I'm pulling it wrong, can you help here?

Comment: Try to go into the MainPage.xaml.cs, there, you define a new object of your controller.cs and set the data context of the MainPage to the object of your controller. Like this: this.DataContext = new Controller();

Comment: ViewModel is a part of MVVM, which is a design pattern for wpf-applications. You should have a look at that!

Comment: I've been working at this for a while and have found some issues. Because the controller is used for everything, there are some more errors, can you look at my "answer" and see if there's anything to do?

Comment: I've sent it off for edit review :) It'll be in the main question

Comment: Did you change your .xaml code? Try to set the whole controller object as datacontext, not just the list.

Comment: @KFutsche sorry about the delay, I had major bugs elsewhere in my program. I have changed the .xaml to `Text="{Binding Sensors[0]}"`  Did you mean the controller like so: `this.DataContext = Controller;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95369/discussion-between-badja-and-fkutsche).